# PHP read text file and display formatted results

Tags: php, image, text-files

My goal is to use PHP to read data from a text file and display a page based on said data.

The text file would look something like this...

```
joe smith|ceo|chief executive officer|10|14|126
Jane Doe|cfo|chief financial officer|8|12|94
```

What I need to be able to do is read the text file, extract each of the values, separated by the "|" token, and format the output in a table-like display. When reading the text file, the first column (name) equates to a picture, located in a subfolder. Therefore, the output should look something like this...

[image: sample output]

Can anyone out there assist with this request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made anything? What problem have you faced?

Comment: lookup PHP's `file()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Splash, I have not yet coded anything because I'm an extreme noob when it comes to PHP. Thanks.

Comment: `file`, `foreach`, `explode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like that:

I would save the Data in this example in a file called test.csv

But I think you get some problems with the first row. A Space in the src of the img-Tag....

I would replace the space from the Name with str_replace() in the PHP 
and the space in the name of the Pictures with Underscrore "_"

```
<?php  
echo '<table>';
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !==false) {
    $num = count($data);
    //print_r($data);
   echo "<tr> ";
   $row++;
   for ($c=0; $c <= $num; $c++) {
      if ($c==0){
        echo '<td><img src="YOUR/SUBFOLDER/"'.$data[$c] 
        ."/>".$data[$c].'</td>';
      }else{
        echo '<td>'.$data[$c] .'</td>';
    }
  }
    echo "</tr> \n";
}
fclose($handle);
  echo '</table>';
}
```

?>

Hope It Helps :-).
 Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Oh my mistake.
Replace at hte end of the row 42

    .;

withe just one semikolon 
;

Comment: Now, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 53," which is a blank line at the end of the code. Weird.

Comment: If I use only your code and modify it to accommodate my file name and subfolder name, I still get the same "unexpected end of file" error for the last line of the code (?>). Thanks.

Comment: Dropping the period from the end of line 13 (echo '<td>'.$data[$c] .'</td>';) didn't make a difference. Still the same "unexpected end of file" error. Is it possible this error relates to the text file it's reading?

Comment: Please try it again - I hate to format  SourceCode herer.
@me it runs on a Test-Server

Comment: Cool. Now I can see the text from within the file, but the picture is the broken-link picture.

Comment: Yes... You hat to replace "YOUR/SUBFOLDER/" -

For example 
<img src="YOUR/SUBFOLDER/"'.$data[$c] ."/>
replace through
<img src="www/image/what/else/"'.$data[$c]."/>

I do not know your folder Structure :-)

Comment: Yes. I replaced that with my folder info:  "images/", but how does it know to pull a .PNG or .JPG or what have you? In this case, all my images will be .PNG. Thanks again!

Comment: <img src="image/"'.$data[$c].'.png"/>....'
Like That?
Be carefull with the " and ' I used both. One for the src=" Tag
and the ' for seperating HTML-TextStrings from Variables in Php

Insteadt of .png You cam Use .jpg

And normaly it don't run with emptySpaces in the Name of a picture...
Test it :-)

Comment: Thank you so very much for all of your help! It is greatly appreciated!!! It can get pretty tricky when you're mixing those single and double quotes, eh? Thanks again!

Comment: One last question. I see how this code simply reads in the data elements one-by-one and creates the html from that. How can I separate out each one of the data elements so I can use CSS to style them individually? Thanks again.

Comment: replace echo '<table>'; to echo '<table class="myTable">';
the U can Use 
css like

.myTable td{ font-weight:bold;) Or somthing like that :-)

Comment: That works for styling the table as a whole, but how to separate out each item that is read from the text file? In other words, as relates to the text file (joe smith|ceo|chief executive officer|10|14|126), I'd like to be able to style each item separated by the vertical lines. Like to be able to change the background color, width of column, bold typeface, etc. Is that possible?

Comment: I would solve it like That:
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html
Pure CSS

If Not I will Ask in Row 12
if ($c%2==0)
The Modulo Operator to solve this :-)